# How do I convert a JSON structure to an object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a JSON structure like this:

```
{
  id:100
  contactInfo: {
    name: John Doe
    city: New York
  }
}
```

and a corresponding Customer class w/ the following properties including a nested contactInfo class.

```
Customer.id
Customer.contactInfo.name
Customer.contactInfo.city
```

Is it possible to convert the JSON data directly to an instance of the Customer class?

I know how to get an NSDictionary object, but that is very cumbersome and verbose to work with and would rather convert/deserialize the data directly to the Customer class.

EDITED w/ Additional Info:

In other languages I have worked with there is built-in support for deserialization of JSON to custom objects. All you have to do is mark the class as "Serializable" and the JSON is deserialized w/o the need to write custom code in each class.

The NSDictionary object can become very cumbersome if the class has nested classes. It would be much easier to use the custom object properties like this

```
Customer.contactInfo.name
```

rather than

```
[(NSDictionary*)[customerDict objectForKey:@"contactInfo"] objectForKey:@"name"]
```

thus my question about a standard built-in deserializer in Objective-C.

Comment: See my additional info just added in response to the answers thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS5 there if official support for JSON
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think it is cumbersome to work with. A simple way to do it would be to have an initialiser for your customer object that took a dictionary as a parameter.

That way you could get your downloaded data as JSON, deserialise it into a dictionary and then pass it to the initializer to create an object from the dictionary.

Comment: It is cumbersome when you have to work w/ a complex JSON structure containing nested objects. A simple one-level object like a number of samples is easy, but not as applicable in real life situations.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the dozens of JSON libraries will parse your JSON string and turn it into an NSDictionary. You're going to have to deal with an intermediate format if you don't want to write a parser yourself. But, once you have the NSDictionary you can use Key Value Coding (KVC) to set the properties on your object:

```
for (NSString *key in jsonDictionary) {
    [customer setValue:[jsonDictionary objectForKey] forKey:key];
}
```

KVC is built into Cocoa, and defines `setValue:forKey:` for all objects, so you can set properties by name regardless of how they are defined.

You'll have to do something smarter than the loop above to handle your internal ContactInfo class, but you should be able to figure that out. For safety (since the JSON is probably coming over the network) you might want to make a whitelist of keys and loop over that, and use `valueForKeyPath:`/`setValue:forKeyPath:` to handle nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using RestKit api (http://restkit.org/) and its object mapping system...

Here is some wiki : https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping

Answer (score 0):

Write an initializer for your Customer class that takes JSON data as a parameter, something like:

```
-(id)initWithJSONData:(NSData*)data;
```

You can implement that method to do what Abizern suggests: read the data into a dictionary, and then pull whatever values you need out of the dictionary.

If you want to get fancy, another way you could go is to adopt NSCoding in your Customer class, and then create a NSCoder subclass that deserializes JSON data. This could work very much like NSKeyedUnarchiver. Doesn't seem worth the trouble unless you're going to take the same approach with a number of your classes, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [library](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/), you can do the following:

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *customer = [parser objectWithString:jsonString];
```

You can then access your properties using:

```
[customer objectForKey:@"id"];
[[customer objectForKey:@"contactInfo"] objectForKey:@"name"];
[[customer objectForKey:@"contactInfo"] objectForKey:@"city"];
```

You can then use this code in your Customer class' init function. For example:

```
- (id)initWithJSON:(NSString *)jsonString {
    self = [super init]; // or whatever you need here
    if (self) {
        SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *customer = [parser objectWithString:jsonString];

        self.id = [customer objectForKey:@"id"];
        self.contactInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[customer objectforKey:@"contactInfo"] objectForKey:@"name"], @"name", [[customer objectforKey:@"contactInfo"] objectForKey:@"city"], @"city"]
    }
    return self;
}
```